# Jasmine - Method not being called

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

```
var obj = {};

obj.localContext = 'firstTemp';

  obj.call = function(){
    obj.localContext = 'secondTemp';
  };
```

Jasmine-spec:

```
it('value of localContext', function(){
  spyOn(obj, 'call');
  obj.call();
  expect(obj.localContext).toEqual('secondTemp');
});
```

Why is the `obj.call()` method never being called? When I run the spec, the value of `obj.localContext` is still `firstTemp` instead of `secondTemp`

Answer (score 3):

When you create a spy, the default behaviour is to replace the object with a mock that doesn't call the original. Typically you'd use it to test functionality that would otherwise call out to other APIs you don't want to be called - you can test that they *would have been* called, without *actually calling* them.

Jasmine does provide you a way to *also* call the original function though:

```
spyOn(obj, "call").and.callThrough();
```

See the [Jasmine documentation for spies](http://jasmine.github.io/2.4/introduction.html#section-Spies) (unfortunately, linking directly to the `and.callThrough` section doesn't work)

Comment: I tried using `and.callThrough()` but the value of `obj.call` is still being logged as `firstTemp`

Comment: `obj.call` is being called, but I get an error - `Some of your tests did a full page reload!`

Comment: I don't see anything in the code above that would cause a page load. Is the code you're testing with different?

Comment: Yes I am testing the value of `$window.location.obj`. @SpoonMeiser

Comment: Is `$window` some kind of alias for `window`? `window.location` is the URL of the current page - changing it loads a new page. Why would try and attach an object to it?

Comment: From the code above, it looks like you want either `window.obj` or just `obj`

Comment: @SpoonMeiser:: I used same spyOn(obj, "call").and.callThrough(); but promise is not resolving. Can you help me into it? here is link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53629138/how-to-test-and-resolve-controller-data-then-function-promise-and-get-orgin